# GeneXus Patterns: How to debug dkt files?

Tags: c#, sdk, genexus

I want to use the Pattern Category (which is deprecated) using GeneXus 17 U8. With the sample code that is in https://github.com/genexuslabs/category-pattern.

I manage to compile, install and run the pattern in GeneXus 17.

I try to apply the pattern in a Empresas transaction and  it creates the instance, but it gives an error:

========== Pattern generation (CategoryEmpresas) started ========== error: An error occurred while applying pattern instance 'CategoryEmpresas': 'Artech.Common.Diagnostics.GxException' **error: Input file has 1 syntacticals errors AttributeCategoryId.dkt(2,0): error DKT1: Syntax error: irrecoverable syntax error **

Failed: Pattern generation (CategoryEmpresas)

I didn't modify the AttributeCategoryId.dkt file (in fact, I didn't modify any file in the repository) and I can't find what the syntax error could be.

When I compare the dkt file with others that work fine, I can't identify where the error is.

The Windows Event Viewer has the following error:

Timestamp: 18/4/2022 10:46:14 Message: HandlingInstanceID: c51c0798-ff33-416b-8822-8af2c40b9e33 An exception of type 'Artech.Common.Diagnostics.GxException' occurred and was caught.

04/18/2022 10:46:14 Type : Artech.Common.Diagnostics.GxException, Artech.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6f5bf81c27b6b8aa Message : Input file has 1 syntacticals errors AttributeCategoryId.dkt(2,0): error DKT1: Syntax error: irrecoverable syntax error

Source : Artech.Architecture.Common Help link : Exception Data Product : GeneXus 17 Version : 17.0.158023 U8 Exception.Severity : Error TargetSite : Boolean iEca3OpCse(Artech.Architecture.Common.Defaults.IApplyDefaultTarget, Artech.Architecture.Common.Defaults.IDefaultProvider, System.String, Boolean) HResult : -2146232832 Stack Trace : at Artech.Architecture.Common.Defaults.DefaultManager.iEca3OpCse(IApplyDefaultTarget , IDefaultProvider , String , Boolean ) at Artech.Architecture.Common.Defaults.DefaultManager.ApplyDefault(IApplyDefaultTarget target, Boolean canDecline) at Artech.Architecture.Common.Objects.KBObject.Artech.Architecture.Common.Defaults.IApplyDefaultTarget.CalculateDefault() at Artech.Architecture.Common.Defaults.EntityDefault.SetIsDefault(Boolean value, Boolean fireCalculate) at Artech.Architecture.Common.Defaults.EntityDefault.set_IsDefault(Boolean value) at Artech.Architecture.Common.Objects.KBObject.set_IsDefault(Boolean value) at Artech.Packages.Patterns.Engine.PatternInstanceGenerator.GenerateObject(IPatternBuildProcess buildProcess, PatternModel patternModel, PatternObject patternObject, PatternInstance instance, PatternInstanceElement element, ApplySettings settings) at Artech.Packages.Patterns.Engine.PatternInstanceGenerator.GenerateObjects(IPatternBuildProcess buildProcess, PatternModel patternModel, PatternInstance instance, PatternObject patternObject, ApplySettings settings) at Artech.Packages.Patterns.PatternEngine.GenerateInstanceObjects(IPatternBuildProcess buildProcess, PatternModel patternModel, PatternInstance instance, InstanceObjects instanceObjects, ApplySettings settings, ApplyResults results) at Artech.Packages.Patterns.PatternEngine.InternalApplyPattern(PatternInstance instance, ApplySettings settings) at Artech.Packages.Patterns.PatternEngine.ApplyPattern(PatternInstance instance, ApplySettings settings)

Additional Info:

TimeStamp : 18/4/2022 13:46:14 FullName : Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=79a65ef946496ecc AppDomainName : GeneXus.exe

Category: Default Category Priority: 0 EventId: 100

The AttributeCategoryId.dkt content:

```
<%@ Template Language="C#" TargetLanguage="GX" Description="Grid Selected Objects SDT" %>
<%@ Include Name="Constants.cs" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Artech.Patterns.Category" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Artech.Patterns.Category" %>
<%@ Property Name="Object" Type="Artech.Architecture.Common.Objects.KBObject" %>
<%@ Property Name="Part" Type="Artech.Architecture.Common.Objects.KBObjectPart" %>
<%@ Property Name="Instance" Type="Artech.Packages.Patterns.Objects.PatternInstance" %>
<%@ Property Name="Element" Type="Artech.Packages.Patterns.Objects.PatternInstanceElement" %>
<%
    CategoryInstance catInstance = new CategoryInstance(Instance);
%>
<Object Type="Attribute" Id="CategoryId" name="<%= catInstance.AttributesName.CategoryId %>" description="<%= catInstance.AttributesName.CategoryId %>">
      <Properties><Property><Name>Name</Name><Value><%= catInstance.AttributesName.CategoryId %></Value></Property><Property><Name>Length</Name><Value>4</Value></Property><Property><Name>Decimals</Name><Value>0</Value></Property><Property><Name>AUTONUMBER</Name><Value>True</Value></Property><Property><Name>AUTONUMBER_START</Name><Value>1</Value></Property><Property><Name>IsDefault</Name><Value>False</Value></Property></Properties>
 </Object>
```

I need to debug dkt and the apply pattern process to correct this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing this issue, we found that the cause of the syntax error is because the dkt line breaks were UNIX-style (`\n`), while the template parser expects Windows-style line breaks (`\r\ n`).

This was an unfortunate change in publishing the project to GitHub, and then downloading it as a zip. In case of cloning the repository from a Windows Git client, the line breaks should be restored.